# error C2065: 'DWORD_PTR' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, windows

While compiling

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "ProgressDlg.h"
    ....  
    ...  
rItem.lParam   = (LPARAM)(DWORD_PTR) m_lsStatusMessages.back().c_str();
```

> I am getting the error C2065: 'DWORD_PTR' : undeclared identifier

Am I missing any Includes.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/0300699f-4f0d-46dc-9c47-c4f5f0a2356b/

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Assuming you actually use the precompiled headers support in MSVC, this is your problem. You (try to) include `windows.h` before `stdafx.h`. Every line of code **before** `#include "stdafx.h"` is ignored. IIRC MSVC also give some warning about it in some versions.

Either put the `#include "windows.h"` into `stdafx.h` or move it below `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

`DWORD_PTR` is defined in `basetsd.h` but you should include `windows.h`

Comment: My not be the answer. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/0300699f-4f0d-46dc-9c47-c4f5f0a2356b/

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need at least one define. The `basetsd.h` contains something like

```
#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400)
```

or

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0502)
```

You can give it a shot and add

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define WINVER 0x0501
```

before you include your `windows.h` for Windows XP requirement settings.

An overview on preprocessor defines and windows header files can be found  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Tried with it but Dint help , I am using VC++ 6.0 , If it helps at all

Comment: @Subhen: VC6 predates the introduction of DWORD_PTR. You would have to manually update the platform SDK to get it. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723284/