# How to read a text file and append a new row with more details in file?

Tags: java, readfile, writefile

I am reading below  text file content and write it to a console using below code.

```
file content
    
   james;mask;1980
   Mos;josh;1960
```

how can i append a new line calculating a year from year of birth in a new column

```
public class Readfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Create file
        File file = new File("/Users/James/documents/Huber.txt");

        try {
            // Create a buffered reader
            // to read each line from a file.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String ch;
            // Read each line from the file and echo it to the screen.
        
            while ((ch = in.readLine()) != null) {
                
                    System.out.println(ch);

        
            
            }
            
            // Close the buffered reader
            in.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // If this file does not exist
            System.err.println("File not found: " + file);

        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // Catch any other IO exceptions.
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This only reads the file. You need to make an attempt at solving the problem first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the Date Of Birth doesn't exceed current date.

```
        StringBuffer inputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = in.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(ch);
            if(ch.split(";").length < 3){ //data unavailable
                inputBuffer.append(ch).append("\n");
                continue;
            }
            int year;
            try {  //dob not specified
                year = Integer.parseInt(ch.split(";")[2]);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                inputBuffer.append(ch).append(";N/A").append("\n");
                continue;
            }
            int age = LocalDate.now().getYear() - year;
            inputBuffer.append(ch).append(";").append(age).append("\n");
        }

        // Close the buffered reader
        in.close();
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        fileOut.write(inputBuffer.toString().getBytes());
        fileOut.close();
```

Comment: why you are using  getByte() on reading inputBuffer

Comment: Take a look at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463461/why-byte-datatype-is-used-for-file-io-java#:~:text=Java%20was%20designed%20after%20C,mixed%20scripts%20may%20be%20combined.&text=class%20file%20uses%20UTF%2D8,is%20only%20for%20binary%20data.)