# Does Word length == number of bits transferred between memory and CPU per access?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am really confused about the concept of the "word length". 
I know that in 32-bit machine, the memory address has 32 bits. And each memory access transfers 32 bits (4 bytes) to the CPU. 
In 64-bit machine, the address has 64 bits. But does it mean the memory access unit is also 64 bits?

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750439/1673428), the author says "Word: The natural size with which a processor is handling data (the register size)". But it does not explicitly specifies how many bits are transferred between memory and CPU per memory access.

Comment: It's true to strictly word-addressable machines. But the majority of computers are usually byte-addressable. Also a lot of computers has double and quad word load/stores.

Comment: In 32-bit byte-addressable machine, each time the CPU loads 32 bits (1 word) which contains the byte in request from the memory. Am i right?

Comment: No, you are not. That depends on the ISA and the specific instruction the CPU is running. E.g. ARM v7 has LDRH/LDRB/STRH/STRB and they load/store 16bit and 8bit values.

Comment: The largest single memory access is often larger than the word size. Three common reasons for this are double precision FP memory accesses on a 32-bit processor, SIMD registers that are larger than GPRs, and paired memory accesses. (In addition, caches are typically loaded one word at a time, so an access to actual memory will typically be at that granularity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CPU with a cache, data usually only transfers between CPU and memory a whole cache-line at a time. e.g. on a modern x86, a 1B load that hits in cache would not produce any external memory access.

If it missed even in the last-level cache, the memory chips would see a request for the 64B aligned block containing that byte.

Modern x86 CPUs have 16B or [even 32B (256b) data paths between cache and execution units](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/6/).

See also other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

It does not say that because it does not mean that.  Addresses are often 64-bits on a 64-bit machine, but not always.  Data paths are often 64-bits on a 64-bit machine, but not always.

Comment: I'm asking how many bits are transferred between memory and CPU per access. For instance, in 32-bit machine, the smallest accessible unit is 1 byte (8 bits). But memory transfers 4 bytes (which contains the byte in question) to the CPU during this access.

Comment: And *I'm* saying that word size doesn't dictate that.

Comment: @TaoHuang: In a CPU with a cache, data usually only transfers between CPU and memory a whole cache-line at a time.  e.g. on a modern x86, a 1B load that hits in cache would not produce *any* external memory access.  If it missed even in the last-level cache, the memory chips would see a request for the 64B aligned block containing that byte.  Modern x86 CPUs have 16B or [even 32B (256b) data paths between cache and execution units](http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/6/).  See also other links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) to learn more.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's exactly what I found eventually. I wish I could select your comment as the final answer.