# what is the difference between byte and dword in assembly and how to use them

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have an assembly program where it iterates through an array and calculates the sum as it iterates. When i change myArray to byte EDX = 01030203 whereas when i change myArray to DWORD EDX = 00000003 can anyone tell me why this happens

```
.data

    myArray byte 3, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5, 8, 9, 2


.code
main PROC
    
    
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, 9
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray

top:
    mov edx, 0
    mov edx, [esi]
    add eax, edx
    inc esi
    dec ecx
    jnz top




main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Same as the difference between `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` in C.  (And always loading via a `uint32_t*` since EDX is a dword register.  But without strict-aliasing UB since this is asm.)

Comment: There's several things here. First is a duplicate, of what is byte vs. word here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750439/471129.  Second is what happens when you have size-mismatched (e.g. byte) data but use dword-sized loads and stores (you'll load multiple data elements as if together they were a single number).  And third, how to use byte vs. dword, is: use byte-sized loads (e.g. `mov al,...`) with byte data and dword-sized loads with dword-sized data (e.g. `mov eax,...`).

Answer (score 2):

A `dword` takes up 4 bytes, regardless of how "big" the number you wrote there appears to be.

For example:

```
.data myArray dword 1,2,3,4,5
```

In a hex editor, if you looked at the `.data` section of the above assembled program (the .exe file, not the source code document), this is what you would see:

```
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
05 00 00 00
```

Meanwhile if you have the following:

```
.data myArray byte 1,2,3,4,5
```

you would instead see `01 02 03 04 05` in your hex editor.

x86 has different register sizes for loading from memory. When you do something like `mov edx,[esi]`, the `e` in `edx` implies that `esi` is a pointer to data that you declared as a `dword`. The CPU makes this assumption and loads `edx` as if you had declared in your code the following:

```
myArray dword 0x01030203,0x09080507,0x??????02
```

I'm using question marks because since the values were undeclared, they could be anything (probably zeroes but who knows).

The important takeaway is that the CPU *has no idea what type your data actually is.* It relies on the programmer to use the correct destination register sizes for loading and storing. Luckily, this is a pretty easy fix.

```
MOV DL,[ESI]  ;you can also use MOV DH,[ESI]
```

In general, the "main registers" `ax`,`bx`,`cx`,and `dx` follow this pattern:

- `ax` is a 16-bit register. It is the "low half" of `eax`.
- `eax` is a 32-bit register. It is the "low half" of `rax`.
- `al` is the "low half" of `ax`, and `ah` is the "high half" of ax.