# Understanding the Justification for different Pointer Types

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, porting

As a consious decision to create seperate model for pointer and non pointer data types Microsoft came up with a set of Data Types, which was stronly suggested to use them rather than POD like `int`, `__int64`, `long` (both `signed` and `unsigned` version).

The Current Model Microsoft Follows is `IL32P64` which forced all the C Type cast of pointers to Integer Types vulnurable to pointer truncation. This forced them to come up with _PTR Types. For Each of the valid Integer Types (signed unsiged) like `long`, `int` or non POD Types like `DWORD`, they came up with the equivalent notation `DWORD_PTR`, `INT_PTR`.

If we resolve the chain of typedefs, all these types boils down to the following defination

```
#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR;
#else
 typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
#endif

#if defined(_WIN64)
 typedef unsigned __int64 LONG_PTR;
#else
 typedef unsigned long LONG_PTR;
#endif
```

What I would like to know, the reason to create different type defs for each Integer Types and non-POD equivalent rather than creating a single type to be used by all (say just one `INT_PTR` and `UINT_PTR`)

**So Why do I want to know?**

If you are always in MS Platform, its seldom a problem as to what MS Comes up with. Problem happens if your code is poly-platform. You have to define the equivalent types for *nix to make your code portable.

I was planning to create only two Pointer Types say `XI64_PTR` and `XU64_PTR` with an equivalent defination and use it irrespective of what the previous types were.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271748/dword-ptr-int-ptr-long-ptr-uint-ptr-ulong-ptr-when-how-and-why

Comment: @CongXu: If you compare both the questions, they address two different problems.

Comment: "You have to define the equivalent types for *nix" — that's not true. You don't have to. Use types described in C++ standard, and you will be fine, with safe and sound, portable C++ code.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I agree, and so before I do so need to `Understanding the Justification for different Pointer Types` instead of creating one(technically two) in Windows.